# Reading parameters from json using swift 2

Tags: json, swift2

iv'e been trying for few days to get parameters from specific json structure with no success so far. I have a NSDictionary that get json data (i need the mToken and data from mHeader for example)

```
{
"$id" = 1;
mHeaders =     (
            {
        "$id" = 4;
        mPoints = 0;
        mRealLeagueId = 57172a6e2276fe28bcf0d91c;
        mTeamId = 57172a762276fe28bcf0e053;
        mTeamLogo = avatar;
        mTeamName = "Hungry Animals";
    }
);
mToken = "5k8ziTBn0G5Gozs7qz68LCLBfLSgymOcLwRshMax1Q5pZi4bx6hbEOFgupoXrBNNGzsWosLs6KPsK6cG1kk/9o5778Y7JEKfo3CAPXS7qAg=";
mUser =     {
    "$id" = 2;
    mAge = 42;
    mCreateDate = "2016-04-20T07:06:30.507Z";
    mEmail = "email0@gmail.com";
    mFirstName = Alesandro;
    mGender = 1;
    mId = 57172a762276fe28bcf0e06d;
    mLastLogin = "2016-04-21T07:20:40.402Z";
    mLastName = Zohar;
    mLogo = avatar;
    mNick = "Big Boss 0";
    mRegion = Global;
    mTeams =         (
                    {
            "$id" = 3;
            mRealLeagueId = 57172a6e2276fe28bcf0d91c;
            mTeamId = 57172a762276fe28bcf0e053;
        }
    );
    mTokens = 9644998;
};
```

}

Comment: Look closely. `mToken` is not in `mHeader`, it's at the root level of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a dictionary after parsing the json. You need mToken which in root level of the json data, you can simply get the value by

```
jsonDict["mToken"]
```

Your mHeader is an array of dictionary so for getting the value, Do like this

```
for dict in jsonDict["mHeaders"] as! Array<NSDictionary> {
    print(dict["mRealLeagueId"]) //prints 57172a6e2276fe28bcf0d91c
    print(dict["mTeamId"]) //57172a762276fe28bcf0e053
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Good to know it helped.